# Spring/Postman Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported

Tags: spring, rest, postman

I'm using Postman to send the following request:
[image]

My controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = RestPath.CHALLENGE)
public class ChallengeController {

    private final ChallengeService<Challenge> service;

    @Autowired
    public ChallengeController(ChallengeService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Creates a new challenge in the system")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE},
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ChallengeDto create(@ApiParam(value = "The details of the challenge to create") @RequestPart("challengeCreate") @Valid @NotNull @NotBlank ChallengeCreateDto challengeCreate,
                           @ApiParam(value = "The challenge file") @RequestPart("file") @Valid @NotNull @NotBlank MultipartFile file) {
        return service.create(challengeCreate, file);
    }
}
```

I already tried to change the "consumes" to delete the APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE to MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE and also tried to delete it, but none of these helped.

Please tell me if you need more information.
Thanks.

Comment: You could try to use `curl` instead, sometimes postman has strange behaviors

Comment: @GustavoTopete how can I use curl to send a file?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files)

Answer (score 91):

@Rokin Answer is good but dont need to place json in file and upload. You can achieve by passing content type to json object as well. 
Postman support content type options while sending form-data. for further see the below image which is self descriptive.

[image]

Comment: Since this is the most upvoted answer, I am adding this extra gist obtained from @John's answer - Content-Type is a header setting which defaults to `application-octet-stream`. To avoid the error, set the `Content-Type` value in header to contain  `application/json`.

Answer (score 24):

For Spring's @RequestPart to work with json objects, in Postman - you need to send the json object as a **File** instead of **Text**.

Put the contents of **ChallengeCreateDto** in a json file and save it as challenge.json. Then upload this file in Postman with the type as **File**.
I've attached a screenshot of how the request in Postman should be just to make it more clearer.

[image]

You can also use @PostMapping instead of @RequestMapping in the newer versions of Spring as shown here

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@PostMapping()
public ChallengeDto create(@RequestPart("challengeCreate") ChallengeCreateDto challengeCreate, 
    @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return service.create(challengeCreate, file);
    }
```

Comment: Alternativelly you can show the column "Content Type" via three dots menu, and set conent type to `application/json`. Easier than saving json data as a file first.

Comment: This is a hack, for anyone even considering using this - don't. Check out Irfan's answer above.

Answer (score 6):

Using @RequestParam to get string and file will solve this issue. 
In Postman use Content-Type as "multipart/form-data" and in Body define your input as form-data.

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38336206/1606838

Example:

```
 @PostMapping(consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public Output send(@RequestParam String input, @RequestParam MultipartFile file) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Content-Type is a header setting and by default it is not checked and defaults to application-octet-stream.  Just check the box under the headers ribbon item (which once checked defaults to application/json). [image]

Answer (score 3):

Adding `Content-Type` as `application/json` to the headers fixes this issue in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, but it's solved. Check my image link

[image]

Resolved

```
[org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported]
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from product_seq for update
```

So use the content-type in the body. It worked for me.