# Spring Boot - Multipart - Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I want to send a file and a json model at one post request.

My Request Mapping looks like that:

```
    @PostMapping("{id}/files")
    public MyOutput create(@PathVariable String id, @RequestPart("request") MyInput input, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
    // ...
    }
```

The error I receive:

```
{
    "timestamp": "Feb 7, 2019, 3:18:50 PM",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported...,
    "path": "/tests/12345/files"
}
```

Postman request:
http://imgshare.free.fr/uploads/62f4cbf671.jpg

My WebConfig:

```
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.setPrettyPrinting().create();

        final GsonHttpMessageConverter msgConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
        msgConverter.setGson(gson);
        msgConverter.setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        converters.add(msgConverter);

        converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

        //
        converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());

    }
```

Comment: Remove the header you don't need for multipart .

Comment: This answer provides a solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60968768/6853351

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to use instead of this

```
@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file
```

use this

```
@RequestParam(value = "file",required = false) MultipartFile file
```

And be sure you set the request type as multipart/form-data
You can set it from postman in the headers tab.

[image: postman example]

If another object you need to send with multipart file,you can send it as a string and then you can convert it to object at the backend side.

```
  @PostMapping("/upload")
    public void uploadFile(@Nullable @RequestParam(value = "file",required = false) MultipartFile file,
                                            @RequestParam(value = "input", required = false) String st)
    {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        MyInput input = null;
        try {
            input = om.readValue(st, MyInput.class);   //string st -> MyInput input
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Postman request example :

[image]

Comment: One more thing : Just change the type of MyInput object to string and define the variable name as value like @RequestParam(value = "request") String input

Comment: Yes, this works, I know, but is not there a way to use MyInput instead of String?

Comment: I don't know if it is helpful but I updated the answer.I am using like that in my company's professional project.

Comment: Any ideas on how to upload multiple multipart files with content? Using `@RequestParam(value = "files",required = false) MultipartFile[] files` doesn't seem to work. When doing that, I got null in `files`.

Comment: @KshitijBajracharya - If your parameter name that is being posted is "file", then your binding value in the RequestParam annotation should also be "file", regardless of how many files you are sending.