# How to upload image from Postman

Tags: spring-boot

I find a tutorial about how to upload an image in Spring Boot application.
I watched this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

This is my Postman :

[image]

Comment: It looks like your HTTP method is wrong... Please define your endpoint to accept POST request. Look at the source code of the tutorial: You will need @PostMapping("/") for the endpoint you are calling.

Comment: I have an answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575893/spring-boot-multipart-unsupported-media-type/54576308#54576308    hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

When we do image upload, then we needs to encoded the image into `base64`,and that encoded string is passed as `json` string.And,in the back-end we need to decoded the string and make the image.

Install **base-64 NPM package**

`npm install base-64`

**Ex.Like:**

```
"upload_image": { "name": "72397.jpg", "content_type":"image/jpg", "file":"base64string"}
```

**Refer this below image:**
[image: image1]
Hope it helps Thanks

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually solves the question asked. He want to know how to upload from Postman and i don't find a solution in your answer.

Comment: then kindly go with that video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c07IsbSNqfI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Yup, now it helps.

Comment: I mean it.... Look at my comment in the original question. He is not using the correct request method... It is showing 405, so he should fix that before doing anything.