# Spring Boot REST multi part request (file + json) throwing 415 Unsupported Media Type exception

Tags: json, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I am using spring boot version = 1.5.2.RELEASE.
When I am sending multi part file with json object to upload file in postman, It throwing  415 Unsupported Media Type exception.

**This is my controller class.**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/promotion/")
public class JobController {
....
....
....
@RequestMapping(value = "/job/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createJobTest(@Valid @RequestBody JobRequest jobRequest,
            @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile multiPartFile) throws Exception {
```

**My json request class.**

```
 public class JobRequest {
        private String campaignKey;
        private String communicationId;
        private Integer channelId;
        private String templateType;
        private String subject;
        private String frequencyControl;
        private Integer leadsRequested;
        private String keywordRelavance;
        private String scheduledAt;
        private String file;
        private String updatedBy;
        
        //getter and setter
    }
```

**Json request in postman**
[image]

**Multipart file request in postman**
[image]

**Header Content-type**
[image]

But when I removed consumes from controller class and from postman as well like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/job/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
```

then debugger coming in controller class but multi part file value coming
**null** in request object like

[image]

I googled a lot there are many similar questions which already posted but none of them helped me.
Please help me to sort out this mystery.

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you find the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575893/spring-boot-multipart-unsupported-media-type

Answer (score 0):

Check this [File upload along with other object in Jersey restful web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609569/file-upload-along-with-other-object-in-jersey-restful-web-service)

Another way is you can pass whole object in text like you are passing file in form-data and convert in object.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadDocs", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> methodName(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("anyKeyName") String objectString)
```

Than you can convert string to object using

```
Class object = new ObjectMapper().readValue(objectString, Class.class);
```

Comment: Thank for reply, I did same you mentioned above. It working for PUT request not POST request. is there any idea why this happening?

Comment: Still I am facing same issue, any one have any idea what going wrong.

Comment: Postman for Linux Version 6.7.1 linux 4.15.0-58-generic / x64